# Idiomatic way to flatten a list of pairs into a list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

The title should be pretty much explanatory. I have `List<Pair<T, T>>` and I would like to transform it into `List<T>` with all elements from all of the pairs in an idiomatic and (more importantly) **efficient** way.

I know there's [`flatten`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flatten.html) but it's for the case of `List<List<T>>` -> `List<T>`.

For now I came up with two implementations as extension functions:

```
fun <T> List<Pair<T, T>>.flatten(): List<T> {
    val accumulator = mutableListOf<T>()
    this.forEach {
        accumulator.add(it.first)
        accumulator.add(it.second)
    }
    return accumulator
}
```

and

```
fun <T> List<Pair<T, T>>.flatten2(): List<T> {
    return this.fold(mutableListOf()) { accumulator: MutableList<T>, pair: Pair<T, T> ->
        accumulator.add(pair.first)
        accumulator.add(pair.second)
        accumulator
    }
}
```

but they don't seem to be elegant.

Could it be done better (in terms of readability, efficiency and idiomaticness)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think both your solutions are very readable so you don't need much improvement there.

In terms of efficiency, a loop in this case would always be the best, although you should preallocate the list's size to further optimise it:

```
val accumulator = ArrayList<T>(size * 2)
```

In terms of it being idiomatic, I really think that for a simple extension function it doesn't need to be any better than this. The obvious way is to use a `flatMap` as the other answer mentions, however in my opinion this makes it a lot less efficient when it doesn't need to be. Out of the two, the second is more idiomatic and the performance should be identical, so go with your preference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with preallocation! Does using concrete implementation (`ArrayList` here) have any downsides?

Comment: Well there has to be a concrete implementation somewhere, in fact if you look at the source code of `mutableListOf` it creates an `ArrayList` anyway. The only benefit of using the Kotlin function is that maybe in the future they might recommend a more efficient implementation than `ArrayList` and the `mutableListOf` function will be updated to reflect it.

Comment: However generally no, and as an `ArrayList` is backed by an `Array`, it is usually the best choice for most scenarios. It's only downside compared to something like a `LinkedList` is that it has to grow when it runs out of capacity, however when preallocating this issue isn't a factor.

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant I can think of is to use [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html), which is a more general form of `flatten` - doing a `map` before flattening.

```
fun <T> List<Pair<T, T>>.flattenPairs(): List<T> =
        this.flatMap { (x, y) -> listOf(x, y) }
```

This is probably less efficient than your solution though, as it creates a lot of intermediate lists. If you want to avoid that, your last attempt can be cleaned up a little bit like this:

```
fun <T> List<Pair<T, T>>.flatten2(): List<T> =
    this.fold(mutableListOf()) { accumulator, (x, y) ->
        accumulator.apply {
            add(x)
            add(y)
        }
    }
```

- The type annotations on the lambda parameters aren't required.
- The pair can be deconstructed.
- Use the `apply` scope function to reduce the duplicated word `accumulator`.
- Changed to an expression body

Comment: The `.flattenPairs()` is quite compact, I'll have to remember that for another time where efficiency is not that important. Also, thanks for the tips `.flatten2()` looks a lot better now :)

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether efficiency or idiomatic is more important to you, so I tried to address both aspects. So in the end, do you care more about efficiency? @asikorski

Comment: Yeah, out of these two, efficiency would be more important.

Comment: @asikorski In that case specify the initial capacity for the array list like Henry Twist's answer. I can't think of any significant improvements other than that.